# Listing articles by WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, shortcode

I'm a newbie. I need the shortcode to display articles of the category in which we are (but without the current article). Now the code displays, by default, the names of articles from all categories or the category, the number of which the user enters in the parameters.

```
add_shortcode( 'art_related_posts', 'related_posts_function' );
function related_posts_function ($atts) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'count' => 3,
    'category' => $cat,
    ), $atts );
$cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $atts['count'],
    'category__in' => $atts['category'],

    );
$out_posts = get_posts( $args );
$out = '<style>
    .art-rp{
        background: #ddd;
        padding: 20px 20px;
    }
</style>';
$out .= '<ul class="art-rp">';
foreach ($out_posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $out .= '<li><a href="'. get_the_permalink($post->ID) .'">'. get_the_title( $post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
}
$out .= '</ul>';
wp_reset_postdata();

return $out;
}
```

Comment: its working on not. what is the issue?

Comment: the code does not fully work.
The shortcode by default displays a list of articles from all categories.
It is necessary that the default list is displayed only from the category to which the article belongs.
The title of the current article does not need to be listed.
Thanks for editing the code, but it did not help.

Comment: *"Do not hit me"*, What..?